# Cosa significa "numeri e nomi"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Cautamente mi sollevai, scavalcai il trascurabile involto del suo corpo, raggiunsi fra letto e muro la radio militare, lasciata forse in pegno alla tenutaria da qualche caporale americano in bolletta. La canzone che ne sgorgò
>   – l’indice della stazione era fermo su Tunisi – parlava
>   francese; una voce di ragazza, a bassissimo volume, era
>   felice dirimpetto a noi, al di là del tenue braccio di mare,
>   e sporgendosi dal rettangolo di luce, tutto **numeri e nomi**, ci chiamava a dividere giovinezza, salute e speranza: 
>          Un monsieur que je ne connais pas
>   
>          me prendra un soir dans ses bras...

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "numeri e nomi" in questo brano? Ho cercato alla voce "numero" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione. Una ricerca su Google però mi ha mostrato che si tratta di un'espressione abbastanza usata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non è una locuzione vera e propria: sta descrivendo la scala graduata della radio, illuminata presumibilmente dall'interno, che era contrassegnata da una (o più) serie di numeri – le frequenze – e di nomi in corrispondenza delle frequenze delle stazioni emittenti più importanti, una delle quali è quella di Tunisi su cui il narratore trova sintonizzata la radio.

Mutatis mutandis, qualcosa del genere:
[image]